# SQL Server - Dsiplay all rows from LEFT table even when the condition is not met

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, left-join, where-clause

I want to get all Titles and Scores for a Given skill Id, every skill has titles mandatorily but there may not be records in the Answer table matching the condition A.[ServiceId] = 45 in this case i still need to display all the Titles and 0 as score

```
 SELECT T.[Title] AS 'Title', SUM(A.[Total]) AS 'Score' FROM dbo.[Title] T
    LEFT JOIN dbo.[Answer] A
    ON T.[TitleId] = A.[TitleId]
    WHERE T.[SkillId] = 2 AND A.[TypeId] = 21
    AND A.[ServiceId] = 45
    GROUP BY T.[Title]
```

For this purpose i made LEFT Join and still it doesn't display the titles, if i remove the condition A.[ServiceId] = 45 i get Titles displayed but the scores are not accurate

How do i display the titles all the times even though the condition A.[ServiceId] = 45 is not met, display 0 as score

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move the conditions on the `LEFT JOIN`ed table to the `ON` clause of the `JOIN`:

```
SELECT T.[Title] AS 'Title', SUM(A.[Total]) AS 'Score' FROM dbo.[Title] T
LEFT JOIN dbo.[Answer] A
    ON T.[TitleId] = A.[TitleId] AND A.[TypeId] = 21 AND A.[ServiceId] = 45
WHERE T.[SkillId] = 2 
GROUP BY T.[Title]
```

If you put the conditions in the `WHERE` clause, they become mandatory, and rows where the `LEFT JOIN` did not match are filtered out.

Comment: Beat me by a whole 3 seconds ;)

Comment: @Larnu: yes, that was close... FYI I have seen already two answers posted within the same second (that was Gordon and I)...

Answer (score 0):

You have clauses on your table you `LEFT JOIN` to in the `WHERE` but don't handle `NULL`s.  `A.[TypeId] = 21` will never be true when no row was returned from the table `Answer`.

Move the clauses to the `ON`:

```sql
SELECT T.[Title] AS Title,      --Don't use single quotes for delimited identifying as thet are use
       SUM(A.[Total]) AS Score  --for literal strings and thus can be confusing to read. Use " or []
FROM dbo.[Title] T
     LEFT JOIN dbo.[Answer] A ON T.[TitleId] = A.[TitleId]
                             AND A.[TypeId] = 21
                             AND A.[ServiceId] = 45
WHERE T.[SkillId] = 2
GROUP BY T.[Title];
```